# Реализация CTRL + C в библиотеке curses python

Tags: python, консоль

В библиотеке curses на windows терминал переводится в **raw** режим. Который не поддерживает прерывания и другие сигналы. Как можно реализовать самому прерывание? В коде есть бесконечная петля.

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем. Вы дали недостаточно информации, чтобы можно было воспроизвести и/или проанализировать проблему. Как минимум, вам стоит добавить минимальный пример отказа работы этих сочетаний.

Comment: Если же в любых случаях, после импорта этой библиотеки у вас не работают сочетания, то вам, вероятнее всего, стоит отправить отчет об ошибке к создателям библиотеки, а т.к. она встроенная, то надо будет воспользоваться [питоновским bug tracker-ом](https://bugs.python.org/). Вот [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html) написано, как и что надо сделать, чтобы отчитаться об ошибке.

Comment: добавьте поток, который будет мониторить нажатия кнопок и при совпадении изменит глобольную переменную, которая разорвёт петлю.